The React Native APK file does not connect to the backend
When I create the APK file for my mobile application, it does not connect to the backend.
The backend service is a custom server.
The server-side technology is Node.js.
The mobile application uses a REST API for communication.
I developed the mobile app with React Native Expo.
The issue is that when the app is run locally via the Expo Go app, it connects to the backend without any issues. However, when I build the APK file and install it on my device, it fails to connect to the backend. While the app works fine with the backend in development mode through Expo Go, it cannot connect to the backend when converted to an APK and run on the device.
I am looking for a developer with experience in mobile app development, Node.js, and REST APIs to help troubleshoot and resolve the backend connection issue.
Here’s what I have tried:
The app connects to the backend without issues when running via Expo Go, but not with the APK.
I checked the internet permissions on the Android device and used the correct API URL.
I created the APK using EAS Build and completed the necessary configurations, but still, the backend connection is not established.
The connection works in Expo Go, but it does not work in the APK.
